# Turning NSData back to plain text NSString

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsdata

I have a simple NSString and I'm converting it to NSData :

```
NSData *data = [[NSData dataWithBytes:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@",%@",self.targetId] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] 
                              length:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@",%@",self.targetId] lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]] retain];
```

Now I want to get the plain text from the NSData object.

If I'm doing that :

```
NSString* dataStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",data];
```

- I'm getting just an hex expression (i.e <9c3f473e 02000000 0b0000>) and not the plain string I want !

I've tried also using initWithData -

```
    NSString* dataStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

But it always shows gibrish, no matter which encoding I give it.

Can you please help here ?? :)

Comment: Did you try NSUTF8StringEncoding instead of NSASCIIStringEncoding?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to simplify your first code snippet to:

```
NSData *data = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@",%@",self.targetId] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]
```

And then your second decoding snippet will work:

```
NSString* dataStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: Note that you have to release the NSString! It's not autoreleased.

Answer (score 1):

Do following change it will work.

```
NSData *data = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@",%@",self.targetId] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] ;
```

You did NData of data.